# How do I change VS Code's PATH?

Tags: visual-studio-code, path, configuration

Even though `black` works in my terminal, I have to provide the absolute path to it in VS Code settings. This is probably because it's installed under `~/.local/bin/` which is not part of VS Code's PATH.

Where is this PATH set and how can I modify it?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is exactly what your after but, search env in windows search bar, select edit the system environment variables,  select environment variables down the bottom, go to path, this will show you what is in your PATH, you can add or remove things here

Comment: I am on Linux, and I already know how to set my shell's PATH. But it seems like VS Code is not using my shell path.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in your [`settings.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) file:

```json
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "PATH": "~/.local/bin:$PATH",
},
```